# XPM automatically selects workflow activity but errors when saving

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5, workflow

I've modified the OTB Translation Review workflow to remove the *Reject* activity:

[image]

After my translation job comes back from TMS and the workflow enters the *Translation Review* activity I've opened the site in XPM and started the review activity form the *Things to do* area.

When I click **Finish** - the *Accept* activity is automatically selected - expected:

[image]

But, the problem is when I click **Done**, I get and error that the next Workflow activity has not been selected?

[image]

This doesn't happen when I finish the activity via Workflow Administration. The dialog uses a drop-down for the next activity, I can select *Accept* and finish:

[image]

This feels like a bug in XPM.

Comment: The following article may provide some pointers on how/where to debug this issue: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-to-debug-tridion-workflow